# Angular How to decrease size of bundle vendor and main js files

Tags: angular, angular6, lazy-loading

I installed **Install source-map-explorer globally need to decrease bundle files to optimize anlyze**

- To Increase speed of Initial load page I have done

> 1. Lazy loading module with preloading.
> 2. Gulp compress configured for Images and JS files.

**so need to decrease bundle JS files , I didn't see webpack.conf [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508969/webpack-source-maps-pointing-to-minified-bundle) file in my angular 6 project .**

> $ npm install -g source-map-explorer

**package.json**

```
  {
  "name": "cfch",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "gulp && ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod --source-map gulp",
    "prebuild": "gulp"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "webpack-sources": "^1.3.0",
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.7.0",
   }
```

[image: Result]

```
Note:vendor.js and main.js 2.4MB and 222KB
```

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to use source map explorer, or how to decrease your bundle size?

Comment: I need to decrease my bundle js files, because need to increase speed of initial load page.

Comment: As far as I know, source-map-explorer is not used to decrease bundle size; it's only used  to analyze and debug JavaScript (or Sass or LESS) code bloat through source maps.

Comment: so far as loading initial page bundle js files much bigger , so need to decrease size of that bundle js files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 CLI huge vendor bundle: how to improve size for prod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432673/angular2-cli-huge-vendor-bundle-how-to-improve-size-for-prod)

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/grano/optimizing-angular-application-load-performance-6bb796b1a7c1) article would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try "ng build --prod --aot"?

Comment: @StefanGroßmann when i try above got error like that :"NullInjectorError: No provider for n". reference link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739210/angular-5-nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-n   , so need to use either --prod or --aot